# What's the name of the background music which starts at 37:31 in episode 1 of Fate/stay night UBW (2014)?

Tags: music, fate-stay-night

In episode 1, the music starts at around 37:31 or so according to my timestamps, during the fight between Shirou and Lancer inside the main house, right after Shirou blocks the lance and gets cut, and a second before Lancer says 'Hoh'.

I searched entire OST, but seemed to have missed it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely to be ["Face to Face"](https://soundcloud.com/friiki-alonofenyorim/original-5-face-to-face-fate-stay-night-ubw-ost-2015), the 5th song from the OST.